# Android HealthConnect: healthConnectClient.getChanges(token) method does not pull new data from Health Connect app

Tags: android, kotlin, healthconnect

I recently started working with HealthConnect SDK for Android (Kotlin), i am able to check permissions, enable them, revoke them and read data but i am **not able to pull updates** from Health Connect app.

Calling:

```
val response = healthConnectClient.getChanges(nextChangesToken)
```

never return changes (I used HealthConnect Toolbox app to insert new Steps data in healthConnect app, so i am sure there are new changes to be fetched).

I make sure i check and enable permissions (READ steps) before calling the method.

Anyone had similar scenario? i really appreciate any hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would like to share my finding with this issue maybe would help someone out there.
So for me the issue was that i was calling

```
val nextChangesToken = healthconnectClient.getChangeToken(..)
```

everytime i am calling `healthconnectClient.getChanges(nexChangesToken)` (in button click)
which is wrong cause the `nextChangesToken` is for the next call of `getchanges` and will fetch next data if available.

The right way to do it is to call `healthconnectClient.getChangeToken(..)` once (ofcourse there is validation condition that should be checked: since this token valide for 30 day only) and in different action (click button or so) call `getchanges(token)`